# Ensuring good contact between ring terminals and the screw terminals they're bolted to

Tags: connector, wire-terminals, contact, screw-terminal

I'm working on a high-current switching converter for research purposes. Because of the voltages and currents involved, many components use screw terminals to connect to wires. I haven't used screw terminals that needed to be able to carry 100A before, and want to ask:

What is the recommended way to make good electrical contact between screw terminals and ring terminals or PCB pads? Is there an IPC standard for this?

Are there any types of nut or washer that can provide a gas-tight seal? Or am I worrying about things that don't matter, and the seal of a normal tightened nut is more than sufficient?

Comment: Do Not use stainless steel where it will be conducting much current - it is OK as part of the hardware holding a ring lug on to a terminal, but not between the lug and terminal, as stainless steel has a relatively high resistivity.

Comment: Right. Copper and aluminum washers and such. Is there anything about the shape of these that matters, though? Should they have a "biting" surface to cut through the oxide layer, or anything like that, for example?

Comment: Read up on "bonding with dissimilar metals.  Copper, aluminum and iron alloys are probably most common.  For copper and aluminum you use special coatings or deox.  For long term copper installs, you can tin the wires to prevent corrosion.  Aluminum wire is generally avoided except with large wires for cost and weight, although sometimes it's used just for weight.  You might want to read a bit before terminating aluminum, but brush it, use deox, use stranded wire if possible, use a lug designed for the purpose and wire type.  So what kind of wire and lug are we talking here?

Comment: 4 to 2 gauge copper wire, terminated with a crimp-on ring terminal. I know enough not to use aluminum if I can avoid it. The ring terminals have not yet been purchased, so if there's one type that's absolutely essential, we can simply put those on the order instead of the generic ones I was planning to get. Tin-plated copper terminal, of course. I'm mostly wondering about proper washers, nuts, and bolts to use here; should I go for copper wherever possible? I'm not sure how easy it is to get copper bolts.

Comment: For large wires, it's important to use correct torque.  For aluminum wires it is crucial.  For just the question of ring terminals on a bus bar, check for dissimilar metals, use the largest screw size that fits the ring, and the screw should be rated for the tightening torque.  Find a chart that shows torque or compression for the type of terminal you're using, if it's compression, calculate torque from there.  If you can't find a chart specific to the terminal, use the rated tightening torque of the bolt/screw.

Comment: Oh.  For bolts, common grade steel bolts are generally fine unless you have a corrosive environment or anything.  Just the bottom pad surface of the ring connector can carry the rated current, so you'd only have to spring for fancy bolts if you wanted to go above and beyond or have a nice finish.  You don't need self sealing nuts for the sealing(the ones with a plastic ring on the end specifically, but they can be nice for their locking property.  Any lock washer that's compatible with your corrosion rules should be fine unless you have some serious vibration, in which case add some lok-tite.

Comment: For when it's a PCB pad, there are probably numerous  other elements that I'm not familiar with due to the fragility of a PCB compared to a nice plump busbar.  Hopefully the designer of the PCB made sure it was rated for the correct clamping pressure of the ring terminal or even the tightening torque of the largest screw that fits the hole.

Comment: Unfortunately, here I have to play the role of PCB designer as well! I've read that any hole for screw terminals should also have vias, which makes sense; those would act as anchors against rotation that could delaminate it. (also, because the current is so high, the PCB traces will be augmented with a 20 mil or so copper sheet bolted on top, and possibly also soldered to the trace--haven't worked out the details yet)

Comment: Never bolt to a PCB pad (the FR4 WILL flow), instead use a metal terminal press fitted (or similar) into the PCB (Wurth make suitable things (See the Redcube range for ideas)  as do others) with a machined thread in the metal. As far as the then bolted connections are concerned, current flows face to face, not primarily thru the bolt, and a 'disk spring' is a good idea (above the ring terminal obviously) to maintain pressure. Use a torque wrench and maybe a spot of locktite.

Comment: @DanMills What if I need the bolt to go through the PCB? I have large film capacitors with screw terminals that this needs to fit. I can't rotate the bolt, either, so I can't used a threaded PCB insert. I would need some form of in-PCB washer.

Comment: @Hearth PEM might have something, or IIRC ERNI have a double sided version of what is essentially the same thing Wurth do, which might be usable by picking one a diameter up from whatever bolt size your caps use? For a research prototype I might just buy a unit from Wurth (Available at digikey) and then drill out the thread on a lathe or drill press, then install from below (Some of their parts have a clearance hole down the middle).